# Detect http method during save

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

How to check which method (POST or PUT) has been used during Backbone.Model.save()?
I'm trying with following code which obviously fails because `success` method has not `xhr` argument passed.

```
    success: function (model, xhr) {     
        console.log(arguments) // 2 arguments: 1 - model, 2 - json response       
        if (xhr.status === 201) {
            this.publish(
                'message',
                'Model was successfully created',
                'success'
            );
            $('#content').find('button[type=submit]').text('Save');
        } else {
            this.publish(
                'message',
                'Model was saved',
                'success'
            );
        }
    },
```

Comment: Isn't the xhr passed to success?  Looking at the current docs it appears to be.

Comment: it's not - i put comment in my question

Comment: You're right.  Read it too quickly and thought the `resp` was the http response.

Answer (score 1):

You know at the point of saving whether or not the record is new.  You could always just do something like:

```
var isNew = model.isNew();

model.save({
  success: function() {
    if (isNew)
      // handle create
    else
      // handle update
  }
});
```